# Selectively apply a CSS effect on a group of SVG elements

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I draw a group of 3 svg elements: a blue square, a red circle and a green ellipse (see code below).
At the moment when one of these elements is mouse overed, the 3 elements scale up.

I am trying to apply a slightly more complicated behaviour, but without success so far:

. when mouse overing the blue square, then all 3 elements should scale up (this part works),

. when mouse overing the red circle, only the red circle and the blue square should scale up (the green ellipse should not move),

. when mouse overing the green ellipse, only the green ellipse and the blue square should scale up (the red circle should not move).

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour?

```css
.zoom * {
  transition: all .4s;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

.zoom:hover * {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <g id="all_shapes" class="zoom">
    <rect id="square" x="20" y="20" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/>
    <circle id="circle" cx="170" cy="45" r="25" fill="red" />
    <ellipse id="ellipse" cx="170" cy="100" rx="40" ry="25" fill="green" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**EDIT**

The use of CSS only is not mandatory. JavaScript could also be used if easier, maybe by following these steps?

(1) get all elements'id from the group 'all_shapes',

(2) create an array with the id 'square' by default,

(3) append the id of the element being hover,

(4) apply the CSS '.zoom' to the elements of the array.

Comment: #2 and #3 cannot be achieved with CSS only because CSS selectors are cascading in the sense that they can only select for elements coming _after_ them, not _before_ them.

Comment: @Terry Thanks. So I assume I would need some JavaScript? Something like (1) list all elements'id from the specific group called 'all_shapes', (2) select 'square' by default, and (3) add the id of the element being mouse overed? It seems too complicated for such a task, no?

Comment: I have an idea and will test it when i'm home...

Comment: @biberman The general sibling selector `~` only selects downstream siblings, never upstream.

Comment: @Terry: I know...

Comment: @SanjayChoudhary did it way better, then i thought - and with CSS only!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Sanjay Choudhary posted an imo perfect CSS only answer, here is a Javascript way to do it.

---

## plain Javascript

You just have to toggle a class (here `.zoom`) with Javascript, your CSS stays nearly the same:

```css
#all_shapes * {
  transition: all .4s;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

.zoom {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

You first store all elements inside of the group `#all_shapes` with an ID in a var (here `elems`). Then you need two event listeners, one for `mouseover` and one for `mouseleave`.

On `mouseover` you add the class `.zoom` to all elements that are stored in `elems` if the `square` is hovered (`if (event.target.id == 'square')`). Otherwise you add that class only to the event target and the square. On `mouseleave` you remove the class `.zoom` from all elements that are stored in `elems`.

**Working example:**

```js
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('#all_shapes *[id]');

document.querySelector('#all_shapes').addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  if (event.target.id == 'square') {
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      elems[i].classList.add('zoom');
    }
  } else if (!!event.target.id) {
    document.querySelector('#square').classList.add('zoom');
    event.target.classList.add('zoom');
  }
});

document.querySelector('#all_shapes').addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].classList.remove('zoom');
  }
});
```

```css
#all_shapes * {
  transition: all .4s;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

.zoom {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <g id="all_shapes">
    <rect id="square"  x="20" y="20" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/>
    <circle id="circle" cx="170"  cy="45" r="25" fill="red" />
    <ellipse id="ellipse" cx="170"  cy="100" rx="40" ry="25" fill="green" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

---

## jQuery

If you are using jQuery the code gets far simpler. You only need one event listener `hover()` and can omit the detour over the var `elems`, because it is needed only two times and `$('#all_shapes *[id]')` is pretty short so you can use it directly.

**Working example:**

```js
$('#all_shapes *[id]').hover(function() {
  if ($(this).is('#square')) {
    $('#all_shapes *[id]').toggleClass('zoom');
  } else {
    $('#square').toggleClass('zoom');
    $(this).toggleClass('zoom');
  }
});
```

```css
#all_shapes * {
  transition: all .4s;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

.zoom {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg width="500" height="500">
  <g id="all_shapes">
    <rect id="square"  x="20" y="20" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/>
    <circle id="circle" cx="170"  cy="45" r="25" fill="red" />
    <ellipse id="ellipse" cx="170"  cy="100" rx="40" ry="25" fill="green" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

### **multiple groups**

Refering to the comments here is another example for multiple groups with the same elements and independent hover effect for each group.

The difference is that you select the groups by class (here `.all_shapes`) and the elements by a small detour over the parent of the hover target:

```js
$(this).parent().find('...
```

To select the square of the group you could use a class `.square` or an attribute selector like `[id^="square"]` (which means the ID begins with "square").

**Working example:**

```js
$('.all_shapes *[id]').hover(function() {
  if ($(this).is('[id^="square"]')) {
    $(this).parent().find('*[id]').toggleClass('zoom');
  } else {
    $(this).parent().find('[id^="square"]').toggleClass('zoom');
    $(this).toggleClass('zoom');
  }
});
```

```css
.all_shapes * {
  transition: all .4s;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

.zoom {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg width="500" height="500">
  <g id="all_shapes1" class="all_shapes">
    <rect id="square1"  x="20" y="20" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/>
    <circle id="circle1" cx="170"  cy="45" r="25" fill="red" />
    <ellipse id="ellipse1" cx="170"  cy="100" rx="40" ry="25" fill="green" />
  </g>
  <g id="all_shapes2" class="all_shapes">
    <rect id="square2"  x="220" y="20" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/>
    <circle id="circle2" cx="370"  cy="45" r="25" fill="red" />
    <ellipse id="ellipse2" cx="370"  cy="100" rx="40" ry="25" fill="green" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: The jQuery code is great! I tried to make it more general by using a class instead of '#all_shapes' and a regex matching the 'square' id. This is intended to fit the case where I have several groups (e.g. group 1 with id="all_shapes_1' and group 2 with id="all_shapes_2", both with the same class; 'square' could be 'square_1' and 'square_2' respectively). Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I dont't know if i understand it right: You mean one SVG with multiple groups, which have all the same elements rect, circle & ellipse (with different IDs)? And the hover effect should only work for the hovered group?

Comment: Yes exactly. Maybe should I post this question in a new thread?

Comment: No, i think it is just a minor change. I will update my answer after testing...

Comment: Awesome, that's perfect !

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with CSS only.

```css
.zoom * {
  transition: all .4s;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

.zoom:hover *:not(#circle),
.zoom #square:hover ~ *,
.zoom #square:hover, 
.zoom #circle:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.zoom #circle:hover ~ * {
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <g id="all_shapes" class="zoom child">
    <rect id="square"  x="20" y="20" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/>
    <circle id="circle" cx="170"  cy="45" r="25" fill="red" />
    <ellipse id="ellipse" cx="170"  cy="100" rx="40" ry="25" fill="green" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Do you think it would be achievable using a JavaScript function for more convenience (in case if several groups exist)?

Comment: @6PO0222 yes using javascript/jquery you have more control over dom,  so you can do it of course.

Comment: This is great - with pure CSS! @6PO0222 This should be the accepted answer...